# When does Numbers sync spreadsheets?

Tags: ipad, icloud, data-synchronization, numbers

In Numbers, connected to wifi (good bandwidth), after modifying a spreadsheet I go back to "Spreadsheets".

Then I wait for the Arrow **￪** to appear, as it indicates that Numbers is syncing with iCloud.

However, sometimes

- it is instantaneous (does the sync immediately)
- it takes a couple of seconds
- it takes 10~30 seconds, or (rarely) more (stuck?)

So, what does the time it takes to sync depends on? Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: There's no configuration to that. It's supposed to sync ASAP when you save.

Comment: @KevinGrabher I just used it and it was 1 second. A day earlier it was 10...